# Stripe cannot make new subscriptions after canceling a subscription

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Ok... I have customer bob. His user id is `1`.

Bob is already a customer in Stripe and he already has a subscription.

I want to cancel his subscription so I do this:

```
$sub = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($subscriptionId);
$sub->cancel();
```

that works.

now I want to resubscribe him to a plan (doesn't matter which plan, any paid plan)... I put it in a try catch: so I do this:

```
try {
    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
        "customer" => $customerId, // bob's id is 1
        "plan" => "premium-plan"
    ));
} catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {

} catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
        // Error is here
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Api $e) {

} catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {

}
```

the error I get is here: `\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e`

what could be wrong?

Comment: `$e->getMessage()` will tell you why.

Comment: My guess is your default payment method on the customer is invalid/expired/insufficient funds, so when the subscription gets attached, the bank returns an error.  That being said, @ceejayoz is correct.  `$e->getMessage()` will tell you for sure.

Comment: @korben yes that was the problem. I had deleted their card on file in stripe so that's why it threw that error. thanks though!